# Sharing Y-Axis Range for Multiple Horizontal Bar Issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having issues plotting the total y-axis range of multiple horizontal bar graphs to have all the value align to one another and make only visible the y-labels on the far left plot.
I have the dataframe below (data) that I use the pd.Grouper function to group by a time interval before I start creating my figure and axes.   Since Im using a dataframe Im assigning a plot to each of the axes' I create.  The code doesn't plot the values correctly.  If i remove the sharey=y then each plot is displayed correctly but of course not aligned to one common y-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#group by time interval
data_gb = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1min')])
#create and set y-axis range limits from original dataframe
custom_ylim = (data.price.min(), data.price.max())
#number of plots based on number of intervals
numplot = len(data_gb)
# create a tuple of axe names seems like a hack 
axes =  tuple(['ax'+str(n) for n in range(1, numplot+1)])
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, numplot, sharey= True, sharex=True)
#iterate and assign plot to each axes
for (t, prices), ax in zip(data_gb, axes):
    ax.set_ylim(custom_ylim) #this doesn't seem to do anything
    prices.plot.barh('price', stacked=True, ax=ax)
    ax.legend_ = None   
plt.show()


timestamp                  price     colA      colB     colC     colD
2021-09-08 13:30:00+00:00  11.00      0.0  140037.0      0.0      0.0
2021-09-08 13:30:00+00:00  11.01  21963.0   34732.0   2961.0   1190.0
2021-09-08 13:30:00+00:00  11.02  17578.0   15434.0  12309.0      2.0
2021-09-08 13:30:00+00:00  11.03   2493.0   12393.0  11229.0    907.0
2021-09-08 13:30:00+00:00  11.04  17240.0   16406.0   1479.0    100.0
...                          ...      ...       ...      ...      ...
2021-09-08 13:31:00+00:00  11.01   8520.0   22579.0   4031.0    248.0
2021-09-08 13:31:00+00:00  11.02  64626.0   10330.0  11340.0   3862.0
2021-09-08 13:31:00+00:00  11.03  10967.0    5144.0   2621.0    640.0
2021-09-08 13:31:00+00:00  11.04  15168.0    2907.0      0.0      4.0
2021-09-08 13:31:00+00:00  11.05   1279.0       0.0      0.0      0.0
```

Incorrectly plotting.
[image]

Plotted individual without sharing y-axis. You can see the first graph is missing values in the previous plot.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I've removed it and left sharey but it still doesn't work.  If i remove sharey they just become an series of independent plots.  I'm looking to align the y-labels across for all plots.

Comment: when i remove ax.set_ylim(custom_ylim)  and the sharey = False it looks like the second image i posted.  I'm using python 3.7 and matplotlib 3.4..3

Comment: with sharey=True and assigning ax.set_ylim(custom_ylim)  individually by iterating through the axes come up with a completely messed up.    I'm using pandas 1.1.2.

Comment: what additionally information you think i should add to help solve the issue?  We can move this to chat if you want?

Comment: As per the post when I do that it looks like the second one has all the data but i want a common y-axis that encompasses the high and low of price for the entire and each bar is aligned. .

Comment: Yes and I think you mentioned before that it will take the axis of the rightmost plot and that is what it is doing impacting the other plots by not displaying the full data if the other plots don't fall exactly into the y-axis range.   Yes pandas is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas bar plotting doesn't always work intuitive. This makes sharing axes quite complicated. One problem is that the bars don't get a numerical nor a pure categorical tick position. Instead, the bars are numbered `0,1,2,...` and afterwards the ticks get their label.

Another problem is that bars for a numerical column can get a weird conversion to string (e.g. a value `12.34` might get displayed as `12.340000001` due to some floating point weirdness). Some weirdness is visible in your plots, such as `7.4` being displayed instead of `7.40`.

The workaround I propose:

- convert the price column to strings with exactly 2 decimals
- when plotting, set the price as index and reindex to the full price range; this makes that all subplots get this same range
- annoyingly, the full price range needs to be calculated before converting the column to string, and then the range also needs to be converted to string

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some test data
times = np.repeat(pd.date_range('2021-09-08 13:30', '2021-09-08 13:34', freq='1min'), 20)
data = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': times,
                     'price': np.round(np.arange(1100, 1200) / 100 - np.repeat([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.55, 0.9], 20), 2),
                     'colA': np.random.randint(1000, 5000, 100),
                     'colB': np.random.randint(1000, 5000, 100),
                     'colC': np.random.randint(1000, 5000, 100),
                     'colD': np.random.randint(1000, 5000, 100)}).set_index('timestamp')
# calculate the full price range, first numeric, then convert to string
full_price_range = [f'{x:.2f}' for x in np.arange(data['price'].min(), data['price'].max() + 0.0001, 0.01)]
# now convert the price column to strings
data['price'] = data['price'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.2f}')

data_gb = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1min')])

numplot = len(data_gb)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, numplot, sharey=True, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 4))
for (t, prices), ax in zip(data_gb, axes):
    prices.set_index('price').reindex(full_price_range).plot.barh(stacked=True, legend=False, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(t)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas barh with shared y-axis]

Note that the line `axes = tuple(....)` in the original code has no effect, because in the next line the variable named `axes` gets a new value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the workaround but it didn't work when I ran the code the figure popped up with the 5 plots empty with y and x-axis with 0 - 1 values. I will see what i can do with the info you provided.  Thanks again.

Comment: okay so i was cut nd pasting it wrong so i got you example to work so i will integrate with my data and see what happens and select your answer once i got it running.  Thanks again.